# Jasper Reports - Limit number of rows in a group

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a CSV datasource something like this:

```
User,Site,Requests
user01,www.facebook.com,54220
user01,plusone.google.com,2015
user01,www.twitter.com,33564
user01,www.linkedin.com,54220
user01,weibo.com,2015
user02,www.twitter.com,33564
user03,www.facebook.com,54220
user03,plusone.google.com,2015
user03,www.twitter.com,33564
```

In the report I want to display the first 3 rows (max) for each user, while the other rows will only contribute to the group total. How do I limit the report to only print 3 rows per group?

e.g

```
User     Site                Requests
user01 | www.facebook.com    |  54220
         plusone.google.com  |   2015
         www.twitter.com     |  33564
                             | 146034
user02 | www.twitter.com     |  33564
                             |  33564
user03 | www.facebook.com    |  54220
user03 | plusone.google.com  |   2015
user03 | www.twitter.com     |  33564
                             |  89799
```

It is really just the line limiting I am struggling with, the rest is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it, if anyone can come up with a more elegant answer I would be happy to see it, as this feels a bit hacky!

for each item in detail band:

```
<reportElement...  isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
     <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{userGroup_COUNT} < 4]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
```

where userGroup is the field I am grouping by. I only seemed to need the  `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` attribute for the first element.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider to use subreport by querying the grouping fields in the main report and then passing the grouping fields as parameters into the subreport; the merits of this method is to avoid the report engine to actually looping through all un-required rows (although they are not shown) and spending unnecessary server-to-server or server-to-client bandwidth especially when the dataset returned is large